# SqlFunctions.StringConvert in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm attempting to write an expression tree which supports dynamic use of StartsWith on number values. 
The idea is to use this method to build dynamic where queries, based on a user input, and execeute them against EF 6.
I’ve already written a method which works for String values. Can you help me to make the same for non-string values?

Here is what my method looks like:

```
public static  IQueryable<TEntity> WhereDynamic<TEntity>( IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, String propertyName,
                                                          String queryValue )
{
    var startsWithMethodInfo = typeof ( String ).GetMethod( "StartsWith", new[]
    {
        typeof ( String )
    } );

    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter( typeof ( TEntity ), "x" );
    var field = Expression.PropertyOrField( parameterExpression, propertyName );
    var startsWith = Expression.Call( field, startsWithMethodInfo, Expression.Constant( queryValue ) );
    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>( startsWith, parameterExpression );
    return queryable.Where( expression );
}
```

I know that I can use the SqlFunctions.StringConvert method to use StartsWith on number values, but I don’t know how to include it in the expression tree.

**Update**

The code I’ve posted works perfectly, but only for String types. Now I want to change it to work with non-string types as well. The problem why it is now not working for numbers is that EF does not support StartsWith for non-string types. 
This problem can be fixed with a call to SqlFunctions.StringConvert:

```
movies = movies.Where( y => SqlFunctions.StringConvert( 
(Double) y.MovieId).TrimStart().StartsWith( "123" ) );
```

But I don’t know how I can include a call to SqlFunctions.StringConvert in the Expression Tree.
So my question is: How can I change the code above to work with none-string types?

Comment: What happens with the code you have shown? Does it throw an exception creating the expression tree? if so: what exception? Or does it throw an exception evaluating the EF query? if so: what exception? Or is there no exception, but it doesn't work as expected? If so: what is "expected", and what actually happens?

Comment: My code wirks, but for string values only. I’ve updated the question.

Comment: What is the type of `MovieId` in the example?

Comment: Int32... but it should also work with Int16 or Double

Comment: have you tried using reflector or ildasm to reverse-engineer what the C# compiler is doing with your C# code? That is a handy thing to do when constructing expression trees

Comment: No, but how could this help me (I never have worked with ildasm )?

Comment: “how I can include a call to SqlFunctions.StringConvert in the Expression Tree” Just like any other method call: using `Expression.Call()`.